# How can this error be resolved as I try to run android simulation but it is showing error?

Tags: typescript, react-native, android-studio, visual-studio-code, android-emulator

Whenever I run the command `yarn react-native run-android` the error `Error: Command failed with ENOENT: adb shell am start -n com.navigateapp/com.navigateapp.MainActivity -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c` is showing

How can this error be resolved as whenever I want to commit a change it is not showing any changes and the app is build but I have to start it manually

Comment: hello which simulator you used ?

Comment: @MahammadMomin Android Studio

Comment: you need to wipe data from simulator